# How to incorporate multiprocessing into existing python code?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am having a serious problem wrapping my head around using multiprocessing in my existing python code. Below is my program gauss.py which essentially fits a Gaussian to data. What is the correct way to incorporate multiprocessing and run this script multiple times using different input files? Should I create a separate .py script that calls this script as a function? Or, do I include a main section underneath all of the existing code?

Also, I am currently manually entering in the data input file in the command line when executing the script. I'm guessing that will need to be changed to some sort of queue format?

```
import json
import sys
import numpy
import pylab
from numpy import * #log, exp, pi
import scipy.stats, scipy
import pymultinest
import os

#-------

infile = sys.argv[1]
file = infile[-5:]
outfile = "out/test/"+init.target+file

wave,flux = numpy.loadtxt(infile, usecols=(0,1), unpack=True)

import init #initialization file

x       = wave[init.start:init.end]
ydata   = abs(flux[init.start:init.end])
maxy    = max(flux[init.start:init.end])
textpos = (.1*(init.plotmax-init.plotmin))+init.plotmin
systemic= (1.+init.red)*init.orig_wave
cont    = flux[init.low1:init.upp1] #select continuum adjacent to emission line
avg     = sum(cont)/len(cont)

stdev   = numpy.std(cont) #stnd dev of continuum flux
noise   = stdev * numpy.sqrt(ydata / avg) #signal dependant noise

dum = 0

###### GAUSSIAN MODEL ######

def make_gauss(mu, sigma, N):

    s = -1.0 / (2 * sigma * sigma)
    def f(x):
        return N * numpy.exp(s * (x - mu)*(x - mu))
    return f

def model1(pos1, width1, height1):
    gaussian1 = make_gauss(pos1, width1, height1)
    return  gaussian1(x) + avg

def prior(cube, ndim, nparams):
    cube[0] = init.minwave + (cube[0]*init.wave_range)      # uniform wavelength prior
    cube[1] = init.minwidth + (cube[1]*(init.maxwidth-init.minwidth))   # uniform width prior
    cube[2] = init.fluxsigma * stdev * 10**(cube[2]*5)  # log-uniform flux prior 

# ----------------------
# analyse with 1 gaussian

def loglike1(cube, ndim, nparams):
    pos1, width1, height1 = cube[0], cube[1], cube[2]
    ymodel1 = model1(pos1, width1, height1)
    loglikelihood =-0.5 * (((ymodel1 - ydata) / noise)**2).sum()
    return loglikelihood

# number of dimensions our problem has
parameters = ["pos1", "width1", "height1"]
n_params = len(parameters)

# run MultiNest
pymultinest.run(loglike1, prior, n_params, outputfiles_basename=outfile + '_1_', n_live_points = 200, multimodal = False, resume = False, verbose = False)
```

Comment: If you're using python's multiprocessing module, you pass in a function to execute, so you don't need to create a new file. You might also want to look at using ProcessPoolExceutor: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor

Comment: Do you want to "run the script" multiple times… or just run a function in the script?  If you want to run a function multiple times, it's `results = Pool().map(f, input_sequence)`… which will run `results = [f(xi) for xi in input_sequence]` where `f(xi)` is called in parallel.   If you want to run a script in parallel… it'd be better to turn your script into a function, and then see my above code.

Answer (score 0):

You could parallelize the processing inside loglike1.

But it is better to run your script with MPI. For example, "mpirun -np 4" will run your script 4 times. Multinest realises it is in MPI mode and dispatches the likelihood calls. pymultines loads the multinest MPI library automatically if you have mpi4py installed.